# Are $e^t$ and $\sin(t)$ dependent since the Wronskiian vanishes for certain t-inputs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I calculated the Wronskiian of $e^t$ and $\sin(t)$, and got $e^t\cos(t)-e^t\sin(t)$. This would be zero at $t = \sqrt{2}/2$.

I know the Wronskiian has to be non-zero for the solutions to be independent; however, I still think the two solutions are independent in this case.

Can someone please explain why or why I'm wrong?

The differential equation is $y'''' - y = 0$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: But $\sin t$ is not a solution to the equation.

Comment: See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358854/differential-equations-wronskian-fails/1358855#1358855. Note that the differential equation you're looking at is fourth-order, and you're only considering two solutions. If you looked at the Wronskian of a complete basis of the solution space to your equation, such as $\{e^x,e^{-x},\sin x, \cos x\}$, you would find that it never vanished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a set of functions are linearly dependent, the Wronskian will be zero *everywhere*. That is, for all $t$, we will have
$e^t\cos(t)-e^t\sin(t)=0.$
That this is not the case at $t=0$ tells us the functions are independent. Moreover, the Wronskian being zero everywhere is not a sufficient condition for functions to be linearly dependent - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) gives $x^2$ and $x|x|$ as an example where the Wronskian is identically zero, but which are linearly independent.

We can also observe more directly that $e^t$ and $\sin(t)$ are linearly independent: If that were so, we could find some $c$ such that *for all* $t$ we had:
$$e^t=c\sin(t)$$
which is absurd since the right hand is bounded by $c$ and the left hand is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

A set of functions is linearly dependent on an interval $I$ if the Wronskian is $\textit {identically}$ zero there.

In your case, if you pass to the characteristic equation $r^4-1=(r^2+1)(r-1)(r+1)$, you can read off the fundamental set: $\left \{ \cos t,\sin t, e^{t},e^{-t} \right \}$. Now a calculation shows that the Wronskian is not identically zero on any interval.